# get records in order of condition in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select id,title,release_date 
from tbl_movies 
where release_date > '2014-02-20' or release_date=''
order by release_date asc
```

```
 
"id" |  "title"                "release_date"  
"49" |  "Fandry"               |  ""  
"92" |  "Govinda"              |  ""   
"112"|  "Gadad Jambhal"        |   ""  
"114"|  "Aandhali Koshimbir"   |   ""  
"118"|  "Mee Aani U"           |   ""  
"125"|  "Tapal"                |   ""   
"131"|  "Cappuccino"           |    ""  
"129"|  "Sau Shashi Deodhar"   | "2014-02-21"  
"130"|  "Yellow"               | "2014-03-28"
```

i want last two record come first,i cant use desc for it because result is based on ascending date ,last two records are based on first condition , how can i achieve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use expressions in `ORDER BY`, like this:

```
SELECT id, title, release_date
FROM tbl_movies
WHERE release_date > '2014-02-20' or release_date = ''
ORDER BY (release_date = '') ASC, release_date ASC
```

The `release_date = ''` expression returns either `true` or `false` which equals 1 or 0 respectivly. You want the false ones first so therefore we sort ascendingly

Comment: thanks Fredrik, its work properly now  can you give detail explanation for your answer

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT id,title,release_date 
FROM tbl_movies 
WHERE release_date > '2014-02-20' or release_date='' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN release_date = '""' Then 1 Else 0 End,DATE(release_date) ASC
```